# How to use Primefaces slider component with decimal values?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using `JSF 2.2`, `Primefaces 4.0`, and I am using `slider` component from `Primefaces`.

```
<p:slider displayTemplate="Between {min} and {max}" minValue="20" maxValue="40" step="1"/>
```

I would like to ask you if is possibile to have `step` as `decimal` value. E.g. `step="0.1"`, or perhaps some ideas about how to solve this issue.

I have tried but I'm getting errors like :

```
javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert 0.1 of type class java.lang.String to int] with root cause
```

Thank you.

Comment: According to the PrimeFaces documentation, step must be an integer. Why not convert your minValue to 200 and maxValue to 400 and use a step of 1 between them. Then when you are ready to use or display the value, divide it by 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As most of the primefaces widgets are based on Jquery UI Widgets,so remove `step` attribute from `<p:slider>` and pass it with `Jquery`

```
<p:slider id="slder" displayTemplate="Between {min} and {max}" minValue="20" 
          maxValue="40" />
```

Script to manipulate this

```
       $(window).load(function(){  // should be  $(window).load to load widget
            $('#slder').slider({
                   step: 0.1
                  });
        });
```

> NOTE : This trick works for any Primefaces widget which is based on
>   Jquery UI widget

Comment: This works if you only need the slider. If you also need the associated text input field that p:slider offers, you need to do much more (make the text field show and accept a decimal separater, make the decimal separator configurable for I18N). At that point it's probably easier to write a JSF component from scratch based on JQuery UI.